# Adding Facebook user's profile data using Parse?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I tried to follow the tutorial “Integrating Parse-Facebook in Unity” at: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-unity 
Everything works fine but when I want to add user’s email, gender, name, birthday and location. , by using the following method :

```
    private IEnumerator saveUserProfile(Dictionary<string, string> profile) {
    var user = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    user["profile"] = profile;

    user["email"] = profile["email"] ;
    user["gender"] = profile["gender"] ;
    user["name"] = profile["name"] ;
    user["birthday"] = profile["birthday"] ;
    user["location"] = profile["location"] ;
    // Save if there have been any updates
    if (user.IsKeyDirty("profile")) {
        var saveTask = user.SaveAsync();
        while (!saveTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;
        UpdateProfile();
    }
    }
```

The only value added is “gender” and the other values were NOT created. Please see the below screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
Also , when I presses on Facebook :” Profile No.” row in “authData” column in Parse database side , the Facebook website open with the following message :
Profile Unavailable
Sorry, this profile is not available at the moment. Please try again shortly

Please what I can do to add the above values and to get the correct profile no. for the users

Thank you

Waheed

Answer (score 0):

try to check your dictionary what are the things being stored.

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in profile)
{
     Debug.Log("Key = " + kvp.Key + " Value = " + kvp.Value);
}
```